# Why is the actionbar so tall on Nexus 7?

Tags: android

For my own entertainment, I'm writing my first android app. On my Nexus 7 in portrait mode, the actionbar looks too tall, for example it is considerably taller than the one in the gmail app (http://www.flickr.com/photos/matthelliwell/8526407062/)

I've ran the same app on an HTC Sensation phone and the actionbar looked more like the height I would expect it. For the style I'm using Theme.Holo.Light with showHome set:

```
<resources>
  <style name="GedcomTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/GedcomActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/GedcomTextView</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/GedcomEditText</item>
  </style>

  <style name="GedcomTextView" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
  </style>

  <style name="GedcomEditText" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
  </style>

  <style name="GedcomActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

The menu itself is created as:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/open_menu_item"
        android:title="Open"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_archive"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete_menu_item"
        android:title="Delete"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

So how do I shrink it on the Nexus without making it excessively small on other devices?

Comment: "I'm not setting any height or styles for the actionbar" -- you most certainly are setting styles that control the action bar, based upon that screenshot. It doesn't even look like an action bar.

Comment: Yes you're right now I look at my code again - I've got holo.light theme set and showHome. You're also right that it doesn't look much like an action bar which is confusing me! I've amended the post to include the styles.

Comment: Solved it: you're comment made me look at the rest of the app to make sure I wasn't missing out anything else. I'd missed out the min sdk version from the manifest. Adding minsdkversion=11 solved it. I'll worry about how to support earlier SDK versions another time.

Comment: Most folk use ActionBarSherlock to support the same action bar construct on older devices.